# Return min date and corresponding amount to that distinct ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, duplicates

Afternoon

I am trying to return the min value/ max values in SQL Server 2005 when I have multiple dates that are the same but the values in the Owed column are all different. I've already filtered the table down by my select statement into a temp table for a different query, when I've then tried to mirror I have all the duplicated dates that you can see below.

I now have a table that looks like:

```
ID| Date   |Owes
-----------------
1  20110901 89
1  20110901 179
1  20110901 101
1  20110901 197 
1  20110901 510
2  20111001 10
2  20111001 211
2  20111001 214 
2  20111001 669
```

My current query:

```
Drop Table #Temp

Select Distinct Convert(Varchar(8), DateAdd(dd, Datediff(DD,0,DateDue),0),112)as Date
,ID
,Paid
Into #Temp
From Table
Where Paid <> '0'

Select ,Id           
       ,Date
       ,Max(Owed)
       ,Min(Owed)          

From #Temp
Group by ID, Date, Paid
Order By ID, Date, Paid
```

This doesn't strip out any of my dates that are the same, I'm new to SQL but I'm presuming its because my `owed` column has different values. I basically want to be able to pull back the first record as this will always be my minimum paid and my last record will always be my maximum owed to work out my total owed by ID.

I'm new to SQL so would like to understand what I've done wrong for my future knowledge of structuring queries?

Many Thanks

Comment: At least to me it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: From my table above for ID 1 I would like to return the Id, the date 01/09/2011 and the min value 89, in the next column I would like to return the max amount for that date for that ID, i.e 510 and work the difference out between the two and so on for ID 2, 3 4 etc? Sorry I don't know if that makes it any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by date you can't also group by `ID`, too, because `ID` is probably unique. Try:

```
Select ,Date
       ,Min(Owed) AS min_date
       ,Max(Owed) AS max_date
From #Temp
Group by Date
Order By Date
```

To get additional values from the row (your question is a bit vague there), you could utilize window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      ,Date
      ,first_value(ID)   OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Owed) AS min_owed_ID
      ,last_value(ID)    OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Owed) AS max_owed_ID
      ,first_value(Owed) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Owed) AS min_owed
      ,last_value(Owed)  OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Owed) AS max_owed
FROM   #Temp
ORDER  BY Date;
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin the first and last will come in handy

Comment: @Woody_1983 FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE aren't in the SQL Server 2005. It is documented to be in Denali (next version of SQL Server) so it probably won't be handy for a little bit

Answer (score 3):

In your "select into"statement, you don't have an Owed column?

GROUP BY is the normal way you "strip out values that are the same".  If you group by ID and Date, you will get one row in your result for each distinct pair of values in those two columns.  Each row in the results represents ALL the rows in the underlying table, and aggregate functions like MIN, MAX, etc. can pull out values.

```
SELECT id, date, MAX(owes) as MaxOwes, MIN(owes) as minOwes
FROM myFavoriteTable
GROUP BY id, date
```

In SQL Server 2005 there are "windowing functions" that allow you to use aggregate functions on groups of records, without grouping.  An example below.  You will get one row for each row in the table:

```
 SELECT id, date, owes, 
 MAX(Owes) over (PARTITION BY  select, id) AS MaxOwes,
 MIN(Owes) over (PARTITION BY select, id) AS MinOwes
 FROM myfavoriteTable
```

If you name a column "MinOwes" it might sound like you're just fishing tho.

Comment: Thanks MakeMinePanacea and the joke at the end made me chuckle!!